# Angular 6 multiple dynamic Charts.js not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I'm trying to make a dynamical charts page for my Final Project on my bachelor. First of all, I have a metric database in SQL, which is retrieved this way.

```
getmetrics(flag = 2) {
  this.metricService.getmetrics()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.metricService.metrics = res as metric[];
    for (let metric of this.metricService.metrics) {
      metric.canvas = "canvas" + metric.id_metric;
    }
    if (flag == 2) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.metricService.metrics.length; i++) {
        //here we create the chart with createCharts(metric);
        this.metricService.metrics[i] = this.createCharts(this.metricService.metrics[i]);

  }
}
```

Flag is used to create the charts after the view is inited,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getmetrics(1);
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.getmetrics(2);
}
```

And create charts looks this way right now to make sure that is only a problem in frontend.

```
createCharts(metric) {
    metric.chart = new Chart(metric.canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 24, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
  return metric;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="col-6 metric" *ngFor="let metric of metricService.metrics">
        <h5>{{metric.nombre}}</h5>
        <div *ngIf = "metric.canvas">
            <canvas id="{{metric.canvas}}">{{ metric.chart }}</canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the result is the following
[Picture of the result without the static chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgiPQ.png)
And it should be like this, but with the first chart on every other canvas.
[Picture of the result with static chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na2S6.png)
Also, is important to say that the result in the result of the static canvas is the following

```
<canvas _ngcontent-c2="" id="canvas0" width="450" height="225" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 450px; height: 225px;"></canvas>
```

And the result in the dynamic (and the objective) canvas is

```
<canvas _ngcontent-c2="" id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Hope this can help, and sorry about my English if I did some mistake on the way.

Comment: I made a workaround to this, refreshing the page every time a chart is add, edited or deleted. Not the best result, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit different. Instead of creating the canvas tag inside a `*ngFor`, I created the chart canvas dynamically at the component code.

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('chart-wrapper');
const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
newCanvas.id = metric.canvas;
wrapper.appendChild(newCanvas);
const ctx = (newCanvas as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
this.lineChart = new Chart(ctx, chartOptions);
```